# Why are the items in panel4d copied?

Tags: python, pandas, panel

This is an example from the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#from-dict-of-panel-objects).

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import *
randn = np.random.randn

data = { 'Label1' : Panel({ 'Item1' : DataFrame(randn(4, 3)) }),
         'Label2' : Panel({ 'Item2' : DataFrame(randn(4, 2)) }) }
p4d = Panel4D(data)
```

The sub-panel `'Label1'` should not contain a dataframe `'Item2'`, however I get a copy of `'Item1'`:

```
In [29]: p4d.ix['Label1','Item1',:,:]
Out[29]: 
          0         1         2
0  0.283740  0.123377  0.122482
1  0.756958  0.618638 -1.732440
2  0.070798 -0.621752 -0.196360
3  0.462558 -1.023808  0.234144

In [30]: p4d.ix['Label1','Item2',:,:]
Out[30]: 
          0         1         2
0  0.283740  0.123377  0.122482
1  0.756958  0.618638 -1.732440
2  0.070798 -0.621752 -0.196360
3  0.462558 -1.023808  0.234144
```

and vice-versa with `'Label2'` and `'Item1'`.

Why does the function Panel4d behaves like this?

I would prefer an empty dataframe (or at least one filled with NaN) rather than a copy. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug. Shows up when fully reindexing (e.g. providing all axes) of a Panel or higher dim object. Shows up in 0.13 and lower versions. The report is here and bug-fix will be in 0.13.1. https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5905

You can workaround by creating a reindexed Panel first

```
In [15]: items = ['Item1','Item2']

In [17]: p1 = Panel({ 'Item1' : DataFrame(randn(4, 3)) }).reindex(items=items)

In [18]: p2 = Panel({ 'Item2' : DataFrame(randn(4, 2)) }).reindex(items=items)

In [26]: p4d = pd.Panel4D({ 'Label1' : p1, 'Label2' : p2 })

In [27]: p4d.ix['Label1','Item1']
Out[27]: 
          0         1         2
0  1.974462 -0.916765 -0.577381
1  0.378009  0.047688 -0.281828
2 -0.288759  0.697560 -0.074013
3 -0.124308  0.908857 -0.042192

[4 rows x 3 columns]

In [28]: p4d.ix['Label1','Item2']
Out[28]: 
    0   1   2
0 NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks. Since in general, we don't know in advance all the items of the panels, I thought of using `items = Index(set(np.concatenate([ panel.items for panel in listOfPanels ])))` to get them, then reindex the panels afteward. Though, I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to do it.